# How to wrap @Html.DisplayFor() with @Html.ActionLink()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I just need to wrap column into hyperlink. So that a user can click on item of Number Column and can be redirected. 
Here is my current View:-

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Read", "Read", new { id = item.id})
        </th>
        <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Trying to do something like this. I know its not right but need to know the right way to do it. I am new to MVC

```
@Html.ActionLink(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number).ToString(), "Read", new { id = item.id })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really, but you *can* just use `Url.Action` instead:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Read", new { id = item.id })">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a way to do this with `ActionLink` (I suspect there isn't, at least not in any way I'd want to support in the code.)  But you can manually craft an `a` tag and still keep its URL dynamic by [using `Url.Action()` instead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492912.aspx):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Read", new { id = item.id })">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Number)
</a>
```